# Third order linear homogenous ode - reduction of order (need help in checking my solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I posted a question a few hours ago about an equation and a member was able to provide helpful insight.

$$y''' + \frac{4x-3}{x(2x-1)}y'' - \frac{2}{x(2x-1)}y' + \frac{2}{x^2(2x-1)}y = 0$$

$$y_1 = x$$

$$y_2 = \frac{1}{x}$$

Here's what I did:

$$y=v(x) \cdot x$$

After finding the derivatives and plugging into the equation, and cancelling some terms, I get the equation:

$$v''' + \frac{2(5x-3)}{x(2x-1)}v'' + \frac{6(x-1)}{x^2(2x-1)}v' =0 $$

Which should be correct since I the un-derived functions of $v$ cancelled out, right?

I can then take that $v' = u$, $u(x)$ and get a second order equation:

$$u'' + \frac{2(5x-3)}{x(2x-1)}u' + \frac{6(x-1)}{x^2(2x-1)}u=0$$

Now, this is a second order equation. From here on, I take that:

$$u=w \cdot \frac{1}{x}$$ and then repeat the process I did above until I get $w$, and from then I can easily obtain $u$. According to my calculations, $$u=C_1 (\frac{1}{x^3} - \frac{1}{3x^3}) + \frac{C_2}{x}$$

Then, remember that $v' = u$, so solving that ODE we get $$v=\frac{-C_1}{3x^2} + C_2 \ln{x} + C_3$$

After which I plug in $v$ in the first substitution and the problem is solved.

$$y=(\frac{-C_1}{3x^2} + C_2 \ln{x} + C_3) \cdot x$$

Could anyone please confirm if this is the correct way to solve these problems? I intentionally left a number of steps out because it would be too long, and since it's my first time dealing with 3rd order ODE of this kind, my focus was on learning *how* to do them. I may have made some mistakes, though I doubt it because I checked with WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Moo Thanks! Typo

Comment: @Moo I tried but I got tangled in the derivatives with a very large expression. What I was looking for is more if my method of finding a solution is correct. If yes, I will spend more time on this exercise by repeating it.

Comment: You can also multiply the whole expression by $x^2(2x-1)$ and take a derivative, yielding a simple Euler equation.